# Matplotlib FuncAnimation put new frame on top of previous ones

Tags: python, matplotlib, animation

I'm new to Matplotlib and trying to create an animated histogram of an array containing 1,000,000 random numbers generated by `numpy.random.randn()`. The first frame is a histogram of 100 first elements of the array. Afterwards, I add one more element to the previous array and plot in a new histogram. I'd like to see each new frame on a clear white background, but in fact the previous frames never disappeared (see the [gif](https://i.stack.imgur.com/niWzi.jpg)). I've been searching for quite some time but couldn't figure out any solution.

Please tell me what is wrong and how to do it correctly? Also, every new frame has different color, how to make it use the same color for all frames?

Below is the code:

```
import numpy as np
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt
import matplotlib.animation as animation
from numpy.random import randn
import seaborn as sns

fig = plt.figure(figsize = (5,5))
ax1 = plt.axes(xlim = (-5,5))
line, = ax1.plot([],[])

x = randn(1000000)

def init():
    plt.clf()
    plt.cla()
    return fig,ax1

def animate(i):
    n = x[:i+99]    
    ax1 = sns.distplot(n,bins=21)
    ax1.set_title("Seaborn distplot, n="+str(i+99))
    return fig

ani = animation.FuncAnimation(fig,animate,init_func = init,interval = 100)

plt.show()
```

Many thanks.

Comment: Move `plt.cla()` to the animate function, and place it above the axis elements.

Comment: @Sameeresque BRUHH, many thanks, this is exactly what I was looking for.

Answer (score 0):

Move `plt.cla()` to the animate function, and place it above the axis elements. This will clear the currently active axes in the current figure, without affecting the other axis elements.